# Как подключить шрифт для вывеления во все браузеры

Tags: html

Классический вариант подключения шрифта font-family: Ubuntu, sans-serif. При таком подключении в safari шрифт имеет другой вид. Как подключить шрифт, чтобы он работал как во всех браузерах одинаково, включая не только chrome,ex,opera, firefox и т.д, но и safari?

Comment: Может начать с [документации](http://htmlbook.ru/blog/svoi-shrift-na-stranitse)?

Comment: Откуда у вас в Safari шрифт Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

sans-serif - это шрифт без засечек. И в разных браузерах он разный - это нормально. Вам нужно подключить свой шрифт в стилях, например так:

```
@font-face{
font-family: 'myfont';
src: url('../fonts/myfont.ttf');
}
```